# Difference between band and group

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

What is the difference between WithinBand and WithinGroup in the [AllowColMoving Enumeration](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.AllowColMoving.html) for setting the [AllowColMoving](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridOverride~AllowColMoving.html) property of an [UltraGrid](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid_namespace.html) control?

Are there any best practices/gotchas regarding this?

Comment: Do they play their own instruments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns can be grouped within a band and when you set AllowColMoving to WithinGroup it would restrict the end user so that they could only move columns within a single group.

For example if you have columns for street, city, state, and zip code you might want the user to only be able to move columns within that group.

To see an example of groups, refer to [Creating Multiple-Row Layout Using Levels](http://help.infragistics.com/Doc/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WinGrid_Creating_Multiple_Row_Layout_Use_Levels.html) topic in the NetAdvantage help.

Comment: That link is now broken

Comment: The title of the topic had changed and that changed the URL in the newer versions of the documentation.  I have updated the link in my answer and it is correct now.